# Is "Class begin!" correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

I remember when I was in the middle school, our English teacher always said "Class begin" to start off a lesson. Usually, the students then would stand up and the teacher said "Hello students!" The students responsed with "Hello teacher!"

But now I feel "Class begin!" doesn't sound grammatical. Shouldn't it be "Class begins!" or "Classes begin!"? I'm also wondering what the teachers usually say when they want to start up a lesson in a class in the English speaking countries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *really* wanted to stretch a point regarding the "grammaticality" of this particular (far from unknown) usage, you could say it's a perfectly valid ***imperative*** - reduced from some "underlying" full form such as...

> *You [the **class**] [please] **begin** [to pay attention!]*
>    ...or the "vocative" (invocation / appeal; I don't know the specific grammatical term)...
>    *[Let the] **class begin***

But honestly, in contexts like this no-one really cares about "grammar". The teacher is simply trying to get the class to pay attention because he's about to start the lesson. But I'd say that *semantically* the initial word ***Class*** is definitely a form of address (to get their collective attention).

It would be just a matter of opinion whether the second word might be interpreted as a cut down version of something more complex, such as *[pay attention as I] **begin** [the formal part of this teaching period]*.

---

In my recollection (going back half a century now! :) it was common for our teachers to say things like ***Simmer down, now!*** But perhaps modern American teachers favour ***Listen up, now!*** Whatever - the idea of there being a "standard, syntactically valid" term for the context is effectively meaningless.

Comment: I'd agree that it's definitely a valid imperative, especially if there's a significant pause between the two words: "Class, begin!"

Comment: @CanadianYankee But it doesn't have any pause between the two words, which sounds less imperative but more narrative. That's why I feel it should be "Class begins".

Answer (score 1):

"Class" can be a form of address. It is how a teacher addresses the students collectively.

> Class, please be seated.
>
> Class, sit down.

**class** can also refer to the students collectively.

> How's your class this semester?
>   -- I have some fast learners, some slow learners, and some in between, as always, but I seem to have more than the usual number of clowns.

Comment: So, it should write : "Class, begin!", not "Class begin!" But in practice, there is no pause between these two words, which sounds more like "Class begin!".

Comment: @dan: What do you mean by "in practice"? Are you referring to native speakers or to what you recall from middle school? If you're referring to native speakers of English, there is indeed a pause between "class" and "begin" or between "class" and "(please) be seated".

Comment: Unless the speaker has said the words so many times that they cease to be spoken naturally, and have become a mindless mechanical ritual.

Comment: I meant what I recall from middle school.